# Gauss-Krüger coordinates to WGS84 in R

Tags: r, coordinate-systems

I need to convert from **Gauss-Krüger** coordinates to **WGS84** coordinates (system uses by Google). I am using **R** to do it, but I don´t find a simple example where this problem is solved.

Could you please help me?

My data for testing the conversion:

Address: Hauptstraße 62
70736 Fellbach, Germany

Input(Gauss-Krüger): 3519358.50 5411371.00

Output (WGS84): 48.839580, 9.262591

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot comment on this so I had to post it as an answer here.  But before I get to the solution, should the output coordinates be reversed?

Solution: (adapted from [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2012-January/014064.html))

```
library(rgdal)
# Creating data
GK <- data.frame(cbind("X_GK"=3519358.50,"Y_GK"=5411371.00))

#Spatial Information, Coordinates Transform
coordinates(GK) <- c("X_GK", "Y_GK")
proj4string(GK) <- CRS("+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +datum=potsdam +units=m +no_defs") # Defining Gauss Krüger
GK.WGS84 <- spTransform(GK, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")) # tranforming to WGS84 longlat

GK.WGS84
```

Output:

```
> GK.WGS84
SpatialPoints:
         X_GK     Y_GK
[1,] 9.262686 48.83949
Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

Comment: It works!!!! Thanks a lot. Only two comments: it is necessary to load the library rgdal. And YES, the coordinates were reversed

Comment: Yes, the redal package is required, in fact, once you load redal, sp will automatically be loaded.  I've edited the answer above.